# Form method "POST" not working in firefox

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net

The following code works in Chrome Version 47.0.2526.73 but on Firefox and IE 11 doesn't work. Any ideea why

HTML:

```
<form action="@Url.Content("~/Account/LogOn/")" method="post" id="login_form">
     <input type="text" id="username" name="username" placeholder="Username" value=""/>
     <input type="password" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" value=""/>
     <button id="btnLogin" class="btn btn-inverse pull-right" type="submit" onclick="OpenPage()">Sign In</button>
</form>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
function OpenPage() {
    $('body').empty().load('../../../Content/LoaderHtml/loader.html');
    return false;
}
```

The code must call an ActionResult method from MVC.

EDIT: Only the onclick event get's fired in Firefox and IE (in Chrome the form also triggers the Controlller's method), if i remove the onclick event everthing works well in firefox and ie and chrome

EDIT2: I need to trigger the onclick event and also to post the form to server (The Chrome behaviour is ok, but how can i make this work even in firefox and IE).

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

The form contains the **submit** button witch is call the **javascript** witch is prevent the form from submit.

```
 <button onclick="OpenPage()">Sign In</button>
```

On your question

> The following code works in Chrome Version 47.0.2526.73 but on Firefox
>   and IE 11 doesn't work.

The `onclick` is called but not return used inline. From the moment that the `OpenPage` function returns false, the correct format must be `onclick="return OpenPage()"` and then on all browsers you have the same response, the form will not submit.

Why the one browser is act different than the others, it may be for that reason, it may be some other javascript error.

### How to make it submit.

`return true;` on your javascript call, and set `onclick="return OpenPage()"`